# find out from which maven repository the jar is coming from

Tags: maven, dependencies, repository

There is a plugin that works properly in my co-worker's system but doesn't in mine. I suspect it because of a repository included in his settings.xml but not in mine. Is there a tool that I can use to figure out from which repo is this plugin being downloaded from?

Answer (score 6):

Maven stores that info in a file called `_maven.repositories` in your local maven repository (typically `~/.m2/repositories`) for each artifact. The file is located right beside the corresponding artifacts in the local maven repository.

This file will typically list the repository / plugin-repository that the artifact was downloaded from.  This matches to the repository from your `settings.xml` file.

Comment: what might cause _maven.repositories (or _remote.repositories) to not contain any useful info?

Answer (score 6):

In Maven 3, the file seems being changed to _remote.repositories